# Read the value of a Elementor Form Field, and use it for the next field

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to create a cascading dropdown in my Elementor Pro Form on Wordpress.
I want to read the value chosen by the user in the earlier dropdown, and then use it to custom populate the second select dropdown.
For example, if the user selects France in the country, we show French cities in the second dropdown,
and if the user selects Germany in the country, we show German cities.

I am able to get the Countries dropdown to show correctly using Custom PHP.
My issue is how to pick up what they have chosen, so that I can show the second dropdown.

I want to do it within Elementor Pro Form, and with help from the functions.php file to write any custom functions.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Dynamic.ooo's "Dynamic Fields". check it out here: https://www.dynamic.ooo/widget/conditional-fields-for-elementor-pro-form/

Comment: Yes Mhdi. I bought dynamic.ooo too. This only allows for the next field to be visible conditionally. But it does not affect the loading of the field unfortunately...